# jquery find command

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Using .find() how to find whether radio button exists in a div or else raise an alert

```
          <div id="emp_form">

          </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) (or just a [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)) and check the [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) like this:

```
if($("#emp_form :radio").length == 0) {
  alert("No radio buttons found!, Crap!");
}
```

Of if you want to do something in the case there are radio buttons:

```
if($("#emp_form :radio").length > 0) {
  //do something
} else {
  alert("No radio buttons found!, Crap!");
}
```

The [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) alternative is `$("#emp_form").find(":radio").length`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
if ($('#emp_form :radio').length != 0) {
    alert('exists');
  } else {
    alert('does not exist');
  }
```

Comment: This *does* need a space between selectors, the radio elements don't *have* that ID, they're *inside* the element with that ID.

Comment: Thanks nick ( radio button are children of div#emo_form ), I forgot to add a space.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( $("#emp_form").find("input[type='radio']").length >0 ) {

} else {
   alert("There is nothing");
}
```

Fixed.

Comment: Your attribute selector needs to be right next to `input`, a space denotes a descendant, so this is currently looking for a `type="radio"` element *inside* an `<input>` which won't exist :)